# Database to use for realtime iPhone app

Tags: sql, ios, database, real-time-data

Me and a friend are going to be working on an iPhone app that is going to be sending and requesting a lot of information from a 24/7 server (a 2009 Mac Mini).  There's going to be a lot of realtime information floating around, and we're not sure what a robust database solution for that info would be.  We're essentially looking for a db that's really fast and powerful, but still pretty simple to use, especially since we'll be accessing it from Objective-C, which is still pretty new for us.  Is Sqlite what we're looking for?  A colleague of ours suggested using PostGres, but isn't PostGres pretty dated?

Comment: Is this database going to be used on the iPhone or the Mac side?

Comment: If it'll run on a 2009 Mac Mini as a "server" then pretty much any RDBMS should suffice.  It's not like you will be deploying an enterprise-level solution that way.  This sounds like the equivalent of wanting to get the best delivery truck for a trip to the grocery store when a minivan will be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is great for the iPhone side. Are you asking about that or the server?

Comment: Yeah, I was actually asking about the server side of things... it's an area I'm admittedly not too familiar with

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure you don't want SQLite. I believe MySQL is the kneejerk answer for server-side databases, but I'm not expert there.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html), Apple's native solution for object graph management and persistence. It uses SQLite internally (though you can set different storage type, including in-memory one), and it is very flexible and optimized.

Comment: Can multiple iPhone clients easily access the Core Data Server DB over Wifi/3G?

Comment: Core Data would be on the iPhone side.

Comment: Yeah, Core Data is a client solution, not server.